# How can I generate exams that contain randomly-generated single-choice answers using R/exams package?

Tags: r, testing, rstudio, random-seed, r-exams

I am interested in using R/exams package in order to generate tests composed of 'single-choice' questions. The three most important things that I am looking for are:

-being able to randomly select one (or more) out of a set of exercises for each participant

-being able to randomly shuffle answer alternatives

-being able to randomly select numbers, text blocks, graphics using the R programming language.

I have followed the basic R/exams tutorials and was able to generate their demo exams, but I was not yet able to find a full tutorial on how to achieve these goals. I am a beginner R programmer and I would, therefore, need a step-by-step tutorial.

If there are any suggestions of such tutorials here I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Use either the R/exams forum on R-Forge or StackOverflow. And when you ask, it helps to be as precise as possible, e.g., with a concrete exercise that does not work as intended etc. Then it's easier to give you precise help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things you are looking for can be accomplished with R/exams. There is not one step-by-step tutorial that illustrates everything, though. But there are quite a few bits and pieces that should get you started.

Do you want to generate written single-choice exams or do you want to conduct your tests in some learning management system like Moodle or so? If you're looking for written exams, then `exams2nops()` is the most complete solution, see:
http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/exams2nops/

For setting up single-choice exercises based on numeric questions, a step-by-step tutorial is: http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/static_num_schoice/

If you prefer an arithmetic illustration rather than one from economics, there is:
http://www.R-exams.org/general/user2019/

For selecting one out of a set of exercises for each participant, you need to define an exam with a list of exercises, e.g.,

```
exm <- list(
  c("a.Rmd", "b.Rmd", "c.Rmd"),
  c("d.Rmd", "e.Rmd")
)
```

When using `exams2xyz(exm)` then you will get an exam with two exercises. The first one is a random sample of `a`-`c` and the second one a random sample of `d`-`e`.

I suggest you try to get started with these, keeping it simple in the beginning. I.e., instead of accomplishing all tasks immediately, try to take them one by one.